# Attaching a public method to a prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype-programming, public-method

This is my code:

```
var Quo = function(string) {            //This creates an object with a 'status' property.
    this.status = string;
};

Quo.prototype.get_status = function() { //This gives all instances of Quo the 'get_status' method, 
                                        //which returns 'this.status' by default, unless another 
                                        //instance rewrites the return statement.
    return this.status;
};

var myQuo = new Quo("confused");        //the `new` statement creates an instance of Quo().

document.write(myQuo);
```

When I run this code the result is `[object Object]`. Since `get_status()` is attached to the `Quo` `prototype`, shouldn't calling the instance of `Quo` be enough to invoke the method? What have I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `document.write(myQuo.get_status());`?

**Update:**

The other option is to overwrite the toString method like so:

```
Quo.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.status;
};
```

Comment: @alnorth29--Yes, that's what works. My question is since the `get_status()` method is attached to the prototype, shouldn't it get invoked automatically when a new instance of `Quo` is called?

Comment: That's not really how it works. The function will be automatically added to all instances of Quo, but that doesn't mean that it will be run when casting the instance to a string.

Comment: @alnorth29--is there a way to write the code so that the prototype method is always called in a new instance?

Comment: If you want a specific string to be returned when casting an object to a string then you can overwrite the object's toString method.

Comment: @alnorth29--would you mind showing me an example? How would the code for that look?

Comment: Sure. In your example you can simply replace get_status with toString. You can see a running example of this at http://jsfiddle.net/ZgFrT/

Comment: @alnorth29--I understand everything except for your use of toString. Isn't toString always meant to be used with a Boolean value? What is the Boolean in this case?

Comment: "Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString